# How can I repurpose the application of Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I want to write a simple webapp that builds on top of the one developed in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails [Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

I tried to simply copy everything in another directory, but I found that the original SampleApp is referenced in various parts of the code.

Before hunting down and kill all the occurrences of the original app I was wondering if there is some clean and recommended way to do this. Any suggestion/hint?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/). It's a great little search tool that can help you find all the occurrences of `SampleApp` and change them to whatever you're going to call your new app.

You'll be looking at changing approximately 9 files. Running `ack <app_name>` on one of my rails apps yielded the following files:

```
config/application.rb
config/environment.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/production.rb
config/environments/test.rb
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/initializers/session_store.rb
config/routes.rb
Rakefile
```

Answer (score 0):

The web app wouldn't be so simple if you were literally copying all of the functionality from the Sample App. If anything, you should expand upon the Sample App (which is what he encourages at the end of the book), and then you can always explain in your README file what changes you've made. Even if you take out all occurrences of the words 'Sample App', you should still give credit to him as well.